# Session not working in Windows service application?

Tags: c#, session, windows-services, session-variables

i am trying to use **Session["emailcc3"]** in windows service application ..but it shows me an error session not available in this context....is there any alternative way to do that??

THIS IS MY CODE:

```
 foreach (DataRow newRow in employee.Rows)
                {
                    num = num - 1;



                    if (num == 4)
                    {
                        Session["emailto"] = newRow["EMAILID"].ToString();
                    }
                    if (num == 3)
                    {
                        Session["emailcc1"] = newRow["EMAILID"].ToString();
                    }
                    if (num == 2)
                    {
                        Session["emailcc2"] = newRow["EMAILID"].ToString();
                    }
                    if (num == 1)
                    {
                        Session["emailcc3"] = newRow["EMAILID"].ToString();
                    }

                }

                string emailto = Session["emailto"].ToString();

                string emailcc1 = Session["emailcc1"].ToString();

                string emailcc2 = Session["emailcc2"].ToString();

                string emailcc3 = Session["emailcc3"].ToString();
```

Comment: "windows service application" and ASP.Net tag? `Session` clearly not available outside of ASP.Net applications - but unclear what you are actually using and what you are trying to achieve by using `Session`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I took a wild guess, I think all that you want is this:

```
string emailto = null;
string emailcc1 = null;
string emailcc2 = null;
string emailcc3 = null;

foreach (DataRow newRow in employee.Rows)
{
    num = num - 1;
    switch (num)
    {
       case 4:
          emailto = newRow["EMAILID"].ToString();
          break;
       case 3:
          emailcc1 = newRow["EMAILID"].ToString();
          break;
       case 2:
          emailcc2 = newRow["EMAILID"].ToString();
          break;
       case 1:
          emailcc3 = newRow["EMAILID"].ToString();
          break;
       default:
          //Do something here?
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why you were using `Session` at all - unless you were using it because it allows you to declare variables on the fly, as it were.